# class design - improving a view_html class

Tags: php

This class provides user created content to the page.

The call is made from html like this:

```
  <?php new route('tweets'); ?>
```

or

```
  <?php new route('bookmarks'); ?>
```

Route instantiates view_html and passes the paramter along.

What improvments that can be made?

```
/*view_html*/

class view_html extends database
  {
  function __construct($type)
    {
    parent::__construct();    
    switch ($type) 
      {
      case "bookmraks":
        $this->bookmarks();
        break;
      case "tweets":
        $this->tweets();
        break;
      default:
        echo "Invalid View Type";
        break;
      }
    }
  private function bookmarks()
    {
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM bo  WHERE email='$email' ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($ass_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {
      $fav=$this->fav($ass_array['url']);
      echo "<img name=\"bo_im\" class=\"c\" src=\"$fav\"/ onerror=\"i_bm_err(this)\"><a target=\"_blank\" name = \"a1\" class = \"b\" href = \"$ass_array[url]\">$ass_array[name]</a>";
      }      
    }
  private function tweets() 
    {
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7");
    $time = time();
    while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {
      echo  "<div class=\"Bb2b\"><img class=\"a\" src=\"p/$a[email].jpg\" alt=\"\"/><a class=\"a\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\">$a[fname] posted <script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write(v0($a[time],$time))</script></a><br/><p class=\"c\">$a[message]</p></div>";
      }
    }
  private function fav($url)     
    {    
    $pieces = parse_url($url);    
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';    
    if(preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs))       
      {     
      return $pieces['scheme'] . '://www.' . $regs['domain'] . '/favicon.ico';    
      }    
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This isn't a "code improvement site". Please limit questions to those allowed in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a code review site, you'd be better off taking this question here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

However, you may want to consider using a switch block instead of if statements in case you want to expand the number of possible types later.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

For the type, you could use a switch case construct in your constructor. The default case could be throwing an InvalidArgumentException.